# Send data from php to C#

Tags: c#, php

I am using C# and I wanna know that how can I send data from php to C# and I found Something Here (I mean in Stack Overflow) but something went wrong.
this is my C# code:

```
 try
        {
            string url = "url";
            string str = "test";
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.Method = "POST";
            string Data = "Message=" + str;
            byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data);
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
            Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            MessageBox.Show(responseText,"Message");
        }
        catch(WebException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Default Message");
        }
```

and this is my php code :

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['Message']))
        {
            $msg = $_POST['Message'];
            echo "Hello World";
        }
        ?>
```

but when I run my program I see anything except Hello World. I mean 
I see this text :(

> function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;fd[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("54cd0d09f741fd28bc51a81fde63b92e");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://programmsn.gigfa.com/MS/Test.php?i=1";This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support

Comment: Have you tried using a different browser? Or activating javascript in the one you are using. based on this ___This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support___

Comment: I didn't used a browser , I just used **HttpWebRequest** Class.

Comment: I don't think the php code you have shown is what is actually at that URL. Test.php is requiring a script called aes.js and HttpWebRequest is not a browser and therefore will not download and execute scripts.

Comment: Ok, I think nginx is injecting content into your responses. I don't know anything about nginx, but you probably have to do something differently to host an API as opposed to web pages.

Comment: Are there any another classes in Visual C# that can do my work and also support JavaScript?

Comment: Is there another way to get data from php?